# Limitar quantidade de caracteres digitados baseado na largura da view

Tags: java, android

Tenho o seguinte `EditText` com largura definida como `match_parent`, basicamente ocupando a largura total independente do dispositivo:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:maxLines="1"/>
```

Esse `EditText` possui no máximo 1 linha e está com propriedade `gravity` como `end`, como podem ver.

Gostaria de limitar a quantidade de caracteres deste `EditText` baseado no seu tamanho. Seria algo como:

```
android:maxLength="largura_total_ocupada_pelo_edit_text"
```

É possível fazer isso, limitar quantidade de caracteres digitados baseado na largura do `EditText`?

Comment: Fiquei intrigado, por que você quer fazer isso, rs?

Comment: De qualquer forma, meu palpite seria usar uma fonte com espaçamento igual entre todos os caracteres, fazer um measure no EditText para pegar a largura em pixels e calcular a quantidade de caracteres que caberia nesse espaço pela largura dos mesmos em pixels.

Comment: @MárcioOliveira a pergunta foi mesmo de curiosidade pra ver de quantas formas seria possível fazer isso.

Comment: Porque acho que a maior dificuldade de se fazer com a fonte nativa é que cada caractere tem um espaçamento próprio e não dá pra prever o que o usuário vai digitar, então você teria que fazer o mesmo cálculo que sugeri só que usando um caractere largo, ex "O".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como foi dito nos comentários da pergunta, para fazer isto você teria que medir o tamanho de cada caractere inserido no `EditText`, e isto não é tão difícil quanto parece.

Fiz em `Kotlin`, pois já que estou utilizando ela em meus projetos, seria mais rápido e fácil. A conversão para `Java` também estará disponível logo abaixo.

Primeiro, e mais importante, devemos saber qual é o tamanho que o `EditText` presente na tela do dispositivo, você pode fazer essa medição utilizando o método [OnGlobalLayoutListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html), pois ele espera que a **view** seja renderizada e então você terá o tamanho correto dela, em **pixels**. Se caso você tentar acessar o tamanho dela diretamente, o valor retornado será **0**.

> Isto retorna zero

```
int inputSize = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputExample)).getWidth();
```

> Isto retorna a largura do componente

```
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputExample)).getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        inputSize = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputExample)).getWidth();
    }
});
```

O mesmo vale para a linguagem *Kotlin*, você também terá que utilizar o mesmo método acima, mas o código pode ficar um pouco mais bonito com algumas implementações da linguagem, como:

```
// https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-ongloballayoutlistener/
inline fun <T: View> T.waitForMeasure(crossinline measure: T.() -> Unit) {
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
        override fun onGlobalLayout() {
            if (measuredWidth > 0 && measuredHeight > 0) {
                viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                measure()
            }
        }
    })
}

// .. MainActivity()
inputExample.waitForMeasure { // inputExample = é uma bind pra view com o kotlin-android-extensions
    inputWidth = inputExample.measuredWidth
    println("Edittext width (PX) is: $inputWidth")
}
```

Pronto, agora nós temos o tamanho que o componente está ocupando na tela do dispositivo, no exemplo acima, eu testei em um **Nexus 5X 1080x1920** e o valor retornado foi `1080`.

Sendo assim, podemos ir para a segunda parte, que é calcular o espaço que o caractere inserido ocupa na tela. Para fazermos isto, temos que utilizar a classe [Paint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) *do próprio componente* para medirmos o caractere com o método [Paint#MeasureText(String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText(java.lang.String)).

> Java

```
int inputWidth = 0
float inputSize = 0.0
int maxCharCount = 0

// O tamanho do EditText primeiro :)
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputExample)).getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        inputSize = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputExample)).getWidth();
    }
});

// A brincadeira começa aqui
((EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputExample)).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence input, int start, int before, int count) {
            Paint paint = inputExample.getPaint() // EditText ID: inputExample...
            inputSize = paint.measureText(input.toString())

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(inputExample.getText().toString())) {
                // Pegar último caractere inserido
                Char char = input[input.length - 1]

               // Pega o espaço restante no EditText
               // Isso depende do tamanho da EditText e do tamanho do TEXTO dela, em pixels.
               // Ex: texto www = 90.0 (w = 30.0) | tela = 1080
               // Espaço restante = 1080-90 = 990
               float spaceLeft = (float) inputWidth - inputSize

               // Pega o tamanho que a letra atual ocupa
               // Ex: letra w = 30.0 ou a = 26
               // Letras maiúsculas e minúsculas diferenciam-se em tamanhos
               // w = 30 | W = 35
               float charSpace = (float) paint.measureText(char.toString())

               if (spaceLeft < charSpace * 1.75) {
                  println("no space left")

                   if (input.length() != maxCharCount) {
                        maxCharCount = input.length()
                   }

               } else {
                   println("hm, there's some space")
                   int charCount = (int) spaceLeft / charSpace
                   maxCharCount = input.length
                   maxCharCount += charCount - (charCount - 1)
               }

               println("Space left: " + spaceLeft)
               println("length: " + maxCharCount)

               // Altera o limite da view de acordo com o espaço restante + tamanho do ultimo caractere inserido (ou o que ainda vai ser inserido)
               // Se tiver espaço: o caractere consegue ser inserido
               inputExample.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxCharCount) } );
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

> Kotlin

```
var inputWidth: Int = 0
var inputSize: Float
var maxCharCount: Int = 0

inputExample.waitForMeasure {
    inputWidth = inputExample.measuredWidth
    println("Edittext width (PX) is: $inputWidth")
}

val listener = object : TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(input: Editable?) {}

    override fun beforeTextChanged(input: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

    override fun onTextChanged(input: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        val paint = inputExample.paint
        inputSize = paint.measureText(input.toString())

        if (input!!.isNotEmpty()) {
            val char = input[input.length - 1]
            val spaceLeft = inputWidth - inputSize
            val charSpace = paint.measureText(char.toString())

            if (spaceLeft < charSpace * 1.75) {
                println("no space left")
                println("Max char count: $maxCharCount")

                if (input.length != maxCharCount) {
                    maxCharCount = input.length
                }

            } else {
                println("hm, there's some space")
                val charCount = (spaceLeft / charSpace).toInt()
                maxCharCount = input.length
                maxCharCount += charCount - (charCount - 1)
            }

            println("Space left: $spaceLeft")
            println("length: $maxCharCount")

            inputExample.filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxCharCount))
        }
    }

}

inputExample.addTextChangedListener(listener)
```

> Demonstração

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Observações**

- O código foi, inicialmente, feito em Kotlin, não em Java. Então, quaisquer erros que vocês encontrarem, sintam-se livres para corrigir/adicionar um comentário.
- Em Kotlin, eu utilizei a referência ao componente **EditText** utilizando o Kotlin-android-extensions, onde eu não preciso ficar utilizando **findViewById**.

Comment: Não fiz teste ainda. Assim quando fizer, valido sua resposta Luc. Vlw. Mas já deixei um +1 pelo desempenho

Comment: Testei com algumas variações de palavras/letras e o resultado foi bem satisfatório. Não fiz um teste bruto, então não posso te dizer se está perfeito ou não, mas sei que dá pra melhorar... então, fique a vontade ;p